# Usage of "ARGV.first"

Tags: ruby, argv

I was trying the following code:

```
user = ARGV.first # supposed to ask for user name
puts "Hi, #{user}. How do you like this?"
```

It does not print as expected. It only prints:

```
Hi, . Do you like me?
```

Can someone give me a hint on this?

Comment: *"ARGV.first # supposed to ask for user name"* -- where this supposition comes from? [`ARGV`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#ARGV) is a constant of class [`Object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html) that is initialized by the interpreter with the arguments passed to the program in the command line. It it already set when your program starts and it doesn't ask for anything.

Comment: @axiac That was the part it was not too clear to me. Now I feel like I understand a little bit more. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

`argv` holds the command line arguments.

```
./your_script.rb USER_NAME
```

… it has nothing to do with reading data from a prompt.

It looks like you are reading [this tutorial](https://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex14.html). You need to read past the first three lines of code.

The code to read from the prompt is on line 7.

> ```
> likes = $stdin.gets.chomp
> ```

Comment: I understood as gets.chomp; and thought it would ask for some name. Cause right in the third line, it greeted the user, I didn't know where the name was coming from. Thank you for your reply!!

Comment: Is ARGV.first just an alias for ARGV[0] or something? I'm trying to find this in ruby docs online but find no reference to a `first` method...

Answer (score 1):

Quentin's given a good answer but he's referring to the "Do you like me?" prompt.

There's no prompt for user name in the Ruby code.

You enter your user name by passing it as an argument to your script.

So, if your script is called "ext14.rb" (as in the tutorial)   you would do...

```
roby ext14.rb Azat
```

This will put "Azat" in the first element of `ARGV` (`ARGV[0]` or `ARGV.first`) so the `user_name` variable will contain the string "Azat"

Comment: Thank you for pointing out what I was missing. It worked. I am gonna dig deeper about ARGV.